# How validate (limit) that, maximum 3 objects can be saved for every month (any interval) by create date?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

In my application user can place products his profile. I want to limit this. Model is:

```
public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
    }
```

When I save product, I need  `AllowedProductSave(userId)`  method to check allowed or not:

```
if (AllowedProductSave(userId))
{
  SaveProduct(productModel, userId);
}
```

Assume that I have all methods like `GetProductsByUserId(), GetUsersFirstProduct(), GetUsersLastProduct()` and other query methods. **I need only limitation logic**, to give permission to user that, he can create only 3 products, for only month. It means, in every 30 days, user can save only 3 products. If he saved 3 product, he will have wait for next 30 days interval to save more 3.

It should be in some way:

**1)** by month name - To check months from 1 to 31.

**2)** by any interval. Interval may be in different months. from 9 February(first product for this interval) to 9 March (last product for this interval)

But its all the same to me.

Product model has `CreateDate` property, if needed I can add other property (for example count). How can I solve this task?

Comment: Just noticed a bug in my logic - the count needs to roll backwards and forwards and hence deleted my answer.

Comment: I used Your idea and changed some:

var before30days = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
var existingProductsInRange = userProducts.Count(x => x.CreateDate >= before30days);

Comment: So products cannot be created in the future then? Would have been nice to know that ;)

Comment: When User want to create product I find his products count in last 30 days.